# regex word boundary space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to replace exact "**çember**" word with "**ögrtmnZZ**" even after another character it has to replace it. (çember, çemberblabla.. etc. -Okay-) But not if the word is in another word.(blablaçember, blablaçemberi etc... -Not Okay-) So i found a regex instead of `\b` anchor (word boundary) because `\b` anchor doesn't know if there is a special character right after it like "**ç, ü, ş, ö, ğ, etc.**", it knows only ASCII code.(well I think) This regex works at the beginning, but it has a space problem, if i type "**çember**" second time, it is not putting a space so it's not working. I don't know how to modify my regex. Any help?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {

    text2 = $(this).val();

    text2 = text2.replace(RegExp("(?:^|\\s)çember(?:$|\\s)", "g"), "ögrtmnZZ");
    text2 = text2.replace(RegExp("(?:^|\\s)çember([abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprqsştuüxwvyzABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPRQSTUÜXWVYZ])", "g"), "ögrtmnZZ$1");

    $("#ta_2").val(text2);

  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>
<textarea id="ta_2" rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A shorter answer: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/f0otfjfo/).

Comment: this is one is better thank you sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I've understood what you're trying to achieve, but you could try this :

```
ac = 'abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprqsştuüxwvyzABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPRQSTUÜXWVYZ';
text2 = text2.replace(RegExp("([^"+ac+"]+|\\s|^)çember([^\\s]*)", "g"), "$1ögrtmnZZ$2");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {

    text2 = $(this).val();

    ac = 'abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprqsştuüxwvyzABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPRQSTUÜXWVYZ';
    text2 = text2.replace(RegExp("([^"+ac+"]+|\\s|^)çember([^\\s]*)", "g"), "$1ögrtmnZZ$2");
    $("#ta_2").val(text2);

  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>
<textarea id="ta_2" rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes that's what im looking for  , thank you so much sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Change non-capturing group to a capturing group then use a backreference in replacement string `$1ögrtmnZZ$2`:

```
text2.replace(RegExp("(^|\\s)çember([abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprqsştuüxwvyzABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPRQSTUÜXWVYZ])", "g"), "$1ögrtmnZZ$2")
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {
    text2 = $(this).val();
    text2 = text2.replace(RegExp("(^|\\s)çember([abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprqsştuüxwvyzABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPRQSTUÜXWVYZ])", "g"), "$1ögrtmnZZ$2")
    $("#ta_2").val(text2);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>
<textarea id="ta_2" rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try running added snippet. By giving `blablaçemberi çemberblabla çemberblabla çemberblabla` as input string it works for me.

Comment: not working :/ when i write **çember**,it types **çember** too :/

Comment: In my snippet I didn't add first replacement line if you see.